# HTTP Error 400 when uploading spatial layer from QGIS to mapsengine using google maps engine connector

Tags: google-app-engine, qgis, google-maps-engine

I installed the "google maps engine connector"-plugin for QGIS in order to upload point data to mapsengine for generating maps to embed in a website. The reason I use QGIS is because the interface is because I can make a direct link with my postgis database which 
is much more convenient than working from the mapsengine interface.

My problem: 
Each time if I try to upload a map from QGIS to my mapsengine profile I get an error:

"Error while fetching https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/upload: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"

I tried using several different datatypes (directly from postgis/postgresql database, shapefile, SQlite) and I simplified my table to the minimum (i.e. id, geometry).

I did some research on google but couldn't find the solution to my problem. Somebody knows how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post any more information about the error? If you can trace the request that you're sending and the full response you are getting back, it will help a great deal.

Comment: I would like to but the log Messages only give me this info. Is there a place in QGIS where you can find more info about an error? I thought maybe to download debugview to track more details of errors but I don't think it is operational on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: I updated the plugin and hopefully that fixes your problem. Can you update to the latest version of the plugin (1.1.3) and try?

Comment: Thank you for solving this problem, it is very much appreciated! The plugin works very smoothly now! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure that this is your problem without seeing the actual requests, but it looks like an issue with the new ACL model in Maps Engine.

Very recently, Maps Engine switched to a per-object permission model (from a named access list model). Details are [here](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/4618526?hl=en).

What this means is that **new projects** cannot create assets using the old model. It looks like the default settings in QGIS are to use the old-style 'draftAccessList' and 'publishedAccessList' settings. You can try leaving the field blank, but I don't have much confidence that it will work.

There are three things I can think of that you can do:

1. [File a bug / FR for the plugin](https://github.com/googlemaps/mapsengine-qgis-connector/issues)
2. If you're desperate, try [patching the plugin yourself](https://github.com/googlemaps/mapsengine-qgis-connector) (an 'if' statement around [this line](https://github.com/googlemaps/mapsengine-qgis-connector/blob/f46c2f71477af82dca5c38ff788fb8135caa8fd2/plugin/upload_dialog.py#L212) looks like the trick)
3. Alternatively, if the data transformation is simple enough you can try to write an import tool yourself using the [Maps Engine API](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/) directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! I reported it as a bug yesterday and now the plugin works!!!